# Why does my gradient stop when viewing on mobile devices?

Tags: background, linear-gradients, css

I have used the following gradient background in CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: #f89623; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#150d03, endColorstr=#f89623); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#150d03), to(#f89623)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #150d03,  #f89623); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
}
```

It works fine in IE, FF Chrome etc. on desktop computers, but the gradient stops when viewed on mobile devices.

The web address is: http://byoma.org/

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What browser are you using on the mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check out the browser compatibility:

[image: Browser compatibility]

But anyway, you should use the example below:

```
.grad { 
background-color: #F07575; /* fallback color if gradients are not supported */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, hsl(0, 80%, 70%), #bada55); /* For Chrome and Safari */
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, hsl(0, 80%, 70%), #bada55); /* For old Fx (3.6 to 15) */
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, hsl(0, 80%, 70%), #bada55); /* For pre-releases of IE 10*/
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, hsl(0, 80%, 70%), #bada55); /* For old Opera (11.1 to 12.0) */ 
background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, hsl(0, 80%, 70%), #bada55); /* Standard syntax; must be last */
}
```

Documentation: [Mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/linear-gradient)

If it doesn't work, I use to resort to this web application: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Thanks for this, but it still doesn't work on Android browser.

Comment: I've updated my answer adding a link to a web application that I use.

Comment: Thanks again but unfortunately that doesn't work either. The gradient still stops and appears in bars.

Comment: So I can't help anymore. I also had issues with showing gradients on Android Browser and solved it thanks to this web site.